# SPSS syntax to connect to database

Tags: sql, syntax, db2, spss

I've successfully connected to a IBM DB2 database in SPSS using the connection wizard. However, I haven't found a working method to do this using SPSS syntax. Has anyone any experience with this?

Comment: After you have established a connection once you can run any query and paste the syntax, and it will contain the necessary connect statement that you can reuse to make other SQL statements. Or are you asking about something else?

Comment: It seems to encrypt the output and if I try and reuse the string it tells me that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides pasting the syntax shown in the last panel of the Database Wizard, which includes the connection string and the SQL that goes with the GET DATA command, you can save the query as an spq file from that last panel and use that again in the Database Wizard by choosing Edit Query in the first step.

Comment: Ok, that is more or less the solution. The problem is that one can't just type in the password into the SPSS syntax.

Comment: So you do need to connect **ONCE** through the Connection Wizard. Then copy and paste the output into a SPSS syntax window. I then removed the SQL query and save the syntax for later use. This way the password will be displayed as some kind of gibberish, but it does work when you rerun the command! THANKS TO EVERYONE.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd access it via this Syntax:
`GET DATA /TYPE =` - insert one of these types - `ODBC,OLEDB,XLS,XLSX,XLSM,TXT`
Whichever is the type that you wish to access, you can also use SQL within the SPSS syntax editor. This is how I connect to my database from the syntax:
`GET DATA
  /TYPE=ODBC
  /CONNECT='DSN=MAVSQL;Description=SQL;UID=;APP=IBM SPSS Products: Statistics '+
    'Common;WSID=MAVNEW;DATABASE=Players;Trusted_Connection=Yes'
  /SQL='SELECT Id, Faction, Active, Level, Name, Allignment, CurQuest, '+
    'PrevQuest, DeathCount, LastDeath, LastLogon, Created, Class, RacAB, '+ 'Comments, Test, Age, RealName, Email FROM dbo.DSOL'
  /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=255.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.`

Hope that helps, I know the database I accessed is a SQL database but perhaps you can use the same methodology to access your IBM DB2 database.